# How could I still log with asp.net healthMonitoring an Exception that was Catch?

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, exception

I configured HealthMonitoring in my web application to log all exceptions in the database.

But, when I gracefully handle some exception by showing a nice message to the user, they are not logged in the database. If I something like `Throw ex`, the standard error page is be displayed and the error is not gracefully handled.

Is there something else I could add at the end of my error handler to tell the system to also log this error?

here an code sample:

```
Dim errorText As String = "Doing Something"
Try
   'Do Something

Catch ex As Exception
        DataActionError.Text = String.Format("There was a problem {0}. ", errorText)
        DataActionError.Visible = True
        'add something here?
End Try
```

and the healthMonitoring section of my web.config :

```
<healthMonitoring enabled="true">
  <eventMappings>
    <clear />
    <add name="All Errors" 
         type="System.Web.Management.WebBaseErrorEvent"
         startEventCode="0" 
         endEventCode="2147483647" />
  </eventMappings>

  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add connectionStringName="MyConnectionString"
         maxEventDetailsLength="1073741823"
         buffer="false" 
         name="SqlWebEventProvider"
         type="System.Web.Management.SqlWebEventProvider" />
  </providers>

  <rules>
    <clear />
    <add name="All Errors To Database" 
         eventName="All Errors" 
         provider="SqlWebEventProvider"
         profile="Default" 
         minInstances="1" maxLimit="Infinite" 
         minInterval="00:00:00" />
  </rules>
</healthMonitoring>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can raise your own events which would then be consumed by the providers.
You can't raise a `WebBaseErrorEvent` yourself, but you can create a custom web event and tweak your configuration to capture it too.
See
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998306
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227980.aspx

Comment: Thanks, the first link was the must helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here the code I used to create and raise my custom web event.

updated code sample :

```
Dim errorText As String = "Doing Something"
Try
   'Do Something

Catch ex As Exception
    Dim ErrorDescr As String = String.Format("There was a problem {0}", errorText)
    DataActionError.Text = ErrorDescr 
    DataActionError.Visible = True

    Dim ErrorEvent As CustomWebEvents.HandeledExceptionWebAuditEvent = _
            New CustomWebEvents.HandeledExceptionWebAuditEvent(ErrorDescr , Ex)
    ErrorEvent.Raise()

End Try
```

HandeledExceptionWebAuditEvent class code  (Note, [I had to put this in a separated assembly to make this work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324486/using-a-class-defined-in-app-code-in-web-config).):

```
using System;
using System.Web.Management;

namespace CustomWebEvents
{
    public class HandeledExceptionWebAuditEvent : WebAuditEvent
    {
        private Exception _ex;

        public HandeledExceptionWebAuditEvent(string msg, Exception ex)
            : base(msg, ex.Source, WebEventCodes.WebExtendedBase + 1)
        {
            _ex = ex;
        }

         public override void FormatCustomEventDetails(WebEventFormatter formatter )
         {
            base.FormatCustomEventDetails(formatter);
            formatter.AppendLine("Activity Description: Handeled Exception");
            formatter.AppendLine("Message:" + base.Message);
            formatter.AppendLine("Exception Message:" + _ex.Message);
            formatter.AppendLine("Exception StackTrace:" + _ex.StackTrace);
         }

    } 

}
```

Updated healthMonitoring section of my web.config :

```
<healthMonitoring enabled="true">
  <eventMappings>
    <clear />
    <add name="All Errors" 
         type="System.Web.Management.WebBaseErrorEvent"
         startEventCode="0" 
         endEventCode="2147483647" />
    <add name="Handeled Exception"
         type="CustomWebEvents.HandeledExceptionWebAuditEvent, CustomWebEvents"
     />
  </eventMappings>

  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add connectionStringName="MyConnectionString"
         maxEventDetailsLength="1073741823"
         buffer="false" 
         name="SqlWebEventProvider"
         type="System.Web.Management.SqlWebEventProvider" />
  </providers>

  <rules>
    <clear />
    <add name="All Errors To Database" 
         eventName="All Errors" 
         provider="SqlWebEventProvider"
         profile="Default" 
         minInstances="1" maxLimit="Infinite" 
         minInterval="00:00:00" />

    <add name="Handeled Exception To Database" 
         eventName="Handeled Exception" 
         provider="SqlWebEventProvider"
         profile="Default" 
         minInstances="1" maxLimit="Infinite" 
         minInterval="00:00:00" />

  </rules>
</healthMonitoring>
```